# Strange behavior when parsing JSON cookie using cookie-react in React / NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a cookie called '_user_attributes'. The cookie contains a URL encoded string of JSON data. For example,

```
%7B%22user_id%22%20%3A%20%2212345%22%2C%20%22user_givenName%22%20%3A%20%22First%22%20%7D
```

which decodes to

```
{"user_id" : "12345", "user_givenName" : "First" }
```

Basically, I want to turn the decoded cookie into an object. So I've been doing the following:

```
var _user_attributes = cookies.get('_user_attributes')
const user_attributes = JSON.parse(_user_attributes)
```

And that works. The strange thing though, is it only works the first time I load the page. If I refresh the page, I get '*SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0*'.

I am completely confused as to why this is the case. If anyone has any suggestions, I would really appreciate it. The full code of my page is below.

```js
import React, { Component, createRef } from "react";
import { withCookies, Cookies } from "react-cookie";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    const { cookies } = props;
    var _user_attributes = cookies.get('_user_attributes')
    const user_attributes = JSON.parse(_user_attributes)
    console.log(_user_attributes)
    this.state = {
      name: user_attributes.name
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <p>{this.state.name}</p>
    );
  }
}

export default withCookies(App);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are encoding the JSON while storing in the cookie but while reading it back cookie value is directly fed to `JSON.parse` without decoding. Since the JSON parser is not able to parse the encoded value, it is throwing the error.

Here is the codesandbox for the working cookie retrieval - https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-shtern-2i4dc?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withCookies } from "react-cookie";

class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { cookies } = props;
    var _user_attributes = cookies.get("_user_attributes");
    if (_user_attributes) {
      _user_attributes = decodeURI(_user_attributes);
      const user_attributes = JSON.parse(_user_attributes);
      console.log(user_attributes);
      this.state = {
        name: user_attributes.user_givenName
      };
    }
    //if the cookie doesn't exist. added just for testing
    else {
      let temp = { user_id: "12345", user_givenName: "First" };
      temp = encodeURI(JSON.stringify(temp));
      cookies.set("_user_attributes", temp, { path: "/" });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return <p>{this.state?.name || "No Cookie yet"}</p>;
  }
}

export default withCookies(Test);
```

But I am not sure how you are able to access the cookie on First load without decoding.

I am able to consistently read the cookie after decoding and parsing on any load of the page. But without decoding I get error all the time.